# Sql server Zip-Up results?

Tags: sql-server

I created this [sql DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/83198) :

I have  #tbl1  :

```
___cola__
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

and  #tbl2  :

```
_colb_
  a
  b
  c
  d
```

I want this :

```
_colb____|__cola____
  a           1
  b           2
  c           3
  d           4
```

I have found a solution ( bad IMHO)

```
SELECT table1.cola, table2.colb FROM
(SELECT cola, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cola) AS rn1 FROM #tbl1) table1,
(SELECT colb, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY colb) AS rn2 FROM #tbl2) table2
WHERE table1.rn1 = table2.rn2
```

For knowledge ,
How **ELSE** can I do it ?

I started with :

`SELECT cola , s.f FROM #tbl1 cross apply(select   colb as f from #tbl2) s`

But there is a problem at the right section.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I just want a new way of doing it. I don't think it's the best elegant solution. and I don't know what ansi-99 style is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an alternative:

```
SELECT cola, colb
FROM (
  SELECT a.cola, b.colb,
         rna=row_number() over (partition by colb
                                order by cola),
         rnb=row_number() over (partition by cola
                                order by colb)
  FROM #tbl1 a
  CROSS JOIN #tbl2 b
  ) X
WHERE rna=rnb;
```

And another:

```
;WITH
 a1 AS (SELECT cola, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cola) AS rn1 FROM #tbl1),
 a2 AS (SELECT colb, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY colb) AS rn2 FROM #tbl2)
SELECT a1.cola, a2.colb
FROM a1
JOIN a2 on a1.rn1=a2.rn2;
```

But to be honest, the 2nd one is just rearranging the parts of the query - the execution plan is exactly the same as what you had.  It works, and is the most efficient plan for such a `zip-up` query.

Comment: Without tagging them with sequential numbers that can be matched 1-for-1, how do you propose SQL Server zips them up?

Comment: @Royi: Why do you think the tables will be scanned twice? They will be scanned once, each of them.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: Your second query (with JOIN) is better than what the OP had because it can easily be changed into an outer join if needed (say FULL JOIN if we don't know the sizes of the tables)

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTE1 as (select col1,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as rn from #tbl1)
,with CTE2 as (select col1,row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as rn from #tbl2)

select c1.col1,c2.col1 from CTE1 c1 inner join CTE2 c2
on c1.rn=c2.rn
```

Comment: Apart from being syntactically incorrect, how is this different from the earlier solution?

Comment: Now that you put that parenthesis in, only the latter part of my question applies.